# Django how do i override model match by field

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I am using django 1.5.5 and python 2.6

I have this model

```
class Site(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
```

I want to customize the model so that site with url that has 'www' prefix and site that dont will return the same object.
So if i have a site with url='http://foo.com' all of the following will return the same object

```
mysite = Site.objects.get(url__iexact='http://foo.com')
mysite = Site.objects.get(url__iexact='http://www.foo.com')
mysite = Site.objects.filter(url__iexact='http://foo.com')
mysite = Site.objects.filter(url__iexact='http://www.foo.com')
```

I was thinking of making a class method like.

```
@classmethod
def get_site(cls,url):
    # search for site with url = url
    if url.startswith('http://www'):
         # search without www
    else:
         # search with www
    return site
```

But i am sure there is a better way so i can keep using `objects.get` and `objects.filter`

### UPDATE:

As suggested by Gonzalo Delgado i made a custom model manager

here is my code

```
def url_variants(url):
prefixes = ['http://www.','https://www.','http://','https://',]  # order must be from longest to shortest
for prefix in prefixes:
    if url.startswith(prefix):
        url = url[len(prefix):]
        break
return [ prefix+url for prefix in prefixes]

class SiteManager(models.Manager):
    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):            
        if 'url' in kwargs:
            variants = url_variants(url)
            # in order to chain '__in' and '__iexact' Q is needed
            q_list = [Q(url__iexact=n) for n in variants]
            q_list = reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, q_list)
            args =  (q_list,) + args            
            kwargs.pop("url", None) # remove original Field lookups
        return super(SiteManager, self).filter(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works good the only problem now is that if i use any kind of Field lookups then it does not use th new logic.
so any kind of `url__in`, `url__contains`, etc does not work.
I am sure there is a better way than to implement each of the filed lookups available in django.

Comment: You probably want to override the get_absolute_url method instead of saving it to the database. Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url)

Comment: There is a builtin field for Urls https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#urlfield

Comment: Also, what's wrong with `Site.objects.filter(url__endswith='foo.com')`? That will match both cases

Comment: @yuvi it will match both but it will also match 'notmy_foo.com'

Comment: There's probably a way to do it with regex. Wait, I'll dig a little

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/) and extend the `get` and filter `methods`:

```
class SiteManager(models.Manager):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'url' in kwargs:
            # handle 'www' prefix here and update kwargs['url'] accordingly
        return super(SiteManager, self).get(*args, **kwargs)


    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'url' in kwargs:
            # handle 'www' prefix here and update kwargs['url'] accordingly
        return super(SiteManager, self).filter(*args, **kwargs)

class Site(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 512)

    objects = SiteManager()
```

Comment: what do yo do when the keyword is for example 'url__exact' or 'url__in' ? how do i cover all the options ?

Comment: There isn't a lot you can do, you can go through all the `kwargs` keys and check for _url_ and each [field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups). Also, my solution doesn't cover queries with Q objects, so it won't work if you need to cover *all the options*. If that's a strong requirement I guess you'll need to make a custom queryset subclass that parses *args and **kwargs (probably in the `_filter_or_exclude` method) and make the manager return instances of that queryset subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution. it is not perfect but i think it is good enough for me.
It is based on Gonzalo Delgado answer.

here is my code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q

def url_variants(urls):
    if isinstance(urls, basestring): # if it is not a list then make a list
        urls = [urls]
    variants = []
    for url in urls:
        prefixes = ['http://www.','https://www.','http://','https://',]  # order must be from longest to shortest
        for prefix in prefixes:
            if url.startswith(prefix):
                url = url[len(prefix):]
                break
        variants += [ prefix+url for prefix in prefixes]
    return variants

def variants_filter(variants,lookup):        
    q_list = [Q(**{ lookup: n}) for n in variants]
    q_list = reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, q_list)
    return (q_list,)

class SiteManager(models.Manager):
    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # find keys that contain 'url'        
        for key in kwargs:
            if key.startswith('url'):                
                variants = url_variants(kwargs[key])                                            
                args = variants_filter(variants, key.replace('__in','')) + args # if there is an '__in' then remove it we already have list support            
                kwargs.pop(key, None)                
                break            
        return super(SiteManager, self).filter(*args, **kwargs)
```